# query that gets only the records needed to the page using Linq- not fetched the record based on page size

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, ienumerable

i have used this query to fetch the Record of the Datatable based on the Pagesize.

```
   IEnumerable<DataRow> query1 = from row in dt.AsEnumerable().Take(page_size).Skip(offset) select row;
```

Datatable boundTable=  query1.CopyToDataTable();

first time when it opens the offset will be =0; it gives 10 records,

next time i pass the offset as 10 to get next ten records,
but it is not giving any enum values. showing me a message says '
Enumeration yielded no results
'

but the dt which i querying has nearly 1000 records. what wrong i made here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `Skip` and `Take` in the wrong order. Try this:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> query = dt.AsEnumerable()
                               .Skip(offset)
                               .Take(pageSize);
```

(I removed the query expression syntax as it wasn't doing you any favours here.)

You were doing `Take` then `Skip` - so you were saying something like, "Give me the first ten records, then skip to the eleventh of those ten." That's clearly not going to give you any results :)

The above says, "Skip to the eleventh record, then give me the first ten records that are left."

Answer (score 1):

Change the order of your Skip and Take.  You're asking the query to Take 10 from the result set, then skip 10 - leaving none.